# openssl s_client ignoring custom root CA certificate in /usr/share/ca-certificates

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openssl

I've set up an Active Directory server and configured LDAP-over-SSL, which works fine for machines on the domain, however because it's using certificates provisioned by AD's Certificate Services it causes issues elsewhere.

I'm trying to connect to the LDAP-over-SSL port from a Debian box using `openssl s_client`, and I'm getting this error:

```
Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
```

I've added my new root CA certificate to `/usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/my-new-root-ca.crt` and run `update-ca-certificates`, and using this command works:

```
openssl s_client -CAfile /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/my-new-root-ca.crt -showcerts -connect my.domain.com:636
```

Whereas this:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect my.domain.com:636
```

nets me these errors at the top of the output:

```
depth=0
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify return:1
depth=0
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
```

Also, this command:

```
ldapsearch -d8 -x -LLL -H ldaps://my.domain.com -D cn=username -w password -b "dc=my,dc=domain,dc=com" -s sub "(objectClass=user)" givenName
```

nets me this output:

```
TLS: can't connect: (unknown error code).
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

So, it looks like neither `openssl s_client` nor `ldapsearch` are picking up the certificate from `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`. Is it actually possible to get openssl to accept my certificate?

Comment: OpenSSL might not be using the trust file that was generated for the system - what about if you point the `-CAfile` at `/etc/ssl/cert/ca-certificates.crt`? (and verify that your cert was added to that file)

Comment: It looks like that's the case. Using /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt works fine, so it isn't automatically picking up the trusted certificates. Is it supposed to do this automatically, or am I assuming that it does and I just needed to verify that the certificate was in the ca-certificates.crt file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenSSL can be a bit.. twitchy.. about what certificates it trusts - sometimes it won't use the system's trusted certificate store.  Adjust its config in the `openssl.cnf` if you're so inclined to make it trust the right store.

For `ldapsearch`, same kind of deal - you'll want to set the trusted certificate in `ldap.conf` to make it actually use the trusted certificate, the option for that is `TLS_CACERT`.

Comment: `TLS_CACERT` did it. `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` was missing, so I looked up a basic config (apparently just `base` and `uri` are enough), then slapped in `TLS_CACERT` and the `ldapsearch` error vanished. Woo! Cheers. :)